# Prevent router navigating to href

Tags: aurelia

I have a link with a `route-href` attribute pointing to one of my routes. This all works fine:

```
<a route-href="route: item; params.bind: {id: item.id}">${item.name}</a>
```

I've now created my own custom attribute `route-popup` which opens the route in a fixed overlay using `<compose>`, this too works fine:

```
<a route-popup="route: item; params.bind: {id: item.id}">${item.name}</a>
```

However, in order for users to be able to Ctrl+click and open items in new windows, I would like to use both `route-href` *and* `route-popup` on the link:

```
<a route-href="route: item; params.bind: {id: item.id}" route-popup="route: item; params.bind: {id: item.id}">${item.name}</a>
```

And then from my `RoutePopupCustomAttribute` class simply `preventDefault()` so that the `route-href` (or `href` it creates) is suppressed:

```
this.onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    this.ea.publish('route-popup:open', {route: this.route, params: this.params});

    return false;
};
```

However, neither `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` or returning `false` from my callback seems to work. Aurelia still follows the `href` and renders the new page.

How can I prevent the router from navigating to the `route-href`?

Edit: Ok so this is a little weird, I set up a gist.run to further explain the problem, however, on gist.run it actually does work :/ All that's needed is `e.preventDefault()`. The only difference in my code is that I'm using `pushState: true` in the router config, so I'm guessing that's it?

https://gist.run/?id=daf226363df8cdc777be718bff3a4f76

Yup, after further testing it turns out that when you use `pushState: true` it's not possible to `preventDefault()` whereas if you use `hashChange: true` it is.

Comment: did you try to set `route-popup` before `route-href` in <a ...>? I mean just switching the order

Comment: I don't think I had tried it before, but sadly it made no difference :/

Comment: If you're still working on this, try adding `return false` to a click delegate on your link: `<a route-href="route: item; params.bind: {id: item.id}" route-popup click.delegate="return false">${item.name}</a>`

Comment: @Nick - that doesn't seem to do anything at all. Besides, I'm already returning false from my custom attribute's click callback.

Comment: did you put a base tag on the page?

Comment: Yea I have `<base href="/">`. Without it nothing works :P